# which minimum angular version is stable for using ui-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am fixing a old angular application and want to integrate ui bootstrap in order for much high end features but the Angular version used in the application is 1.2.18. When updating the angular to any higher version breaks the application . I am looking for a fix in order to use ui bootstrap . What could be the best possible solution.!

Comment: *When updating the angular to any higher version breaks the application*: then, how about fixing it first, by reading the changelog to learn about breaking changes since 1.2.18, and reading the error messages, etc. And then use the latest stable version of ui-bootstrap? Anyway, version compatibility is documented, in the first paragraph of the landing page of the documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @PeaceRider That's really unacceptable language here. There's nothing wrong with asking beginner questions. However, you've gave almost *no* information to allow people to help you. You said you get an error when upgrading. *What* error? You've left out every important detail that might get you a useful answer.

Comment: Hover your mouse on the down vote link. It says "this question does not show any research effort". That's why I downvoted: you didn't even try to read the first paragraph of the landing page of ui-bootstrap, which contains the answer to your question and is 5 lines long. And now you insult people.

Comment: @JBNizet . You are right brother... Thanks for the advice. Was not aware of such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official ui-bootstrap link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.1/)

> Dependencies
>
> The only required dependencies are:
>
> 1. AngularJS (**requires AngularJS 1.2.x, tested with 1.2.16**)
> 2. Bootstrap CSS (**tested with version 3.1.1**). This version of the library (0.12.1) **works only with Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x.**

**Please note that this is an old version of ui-bootstrap library. Current version is 2.5.0 and is tested with AngularJS 1.6.1**

[*All releases from this library can be found here!*](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/releases)

Comment: Your link is for version 0.12.1, which is very very old.

Comment: @JBNizet and it is the latest version stable with AngularJS 1.2.x which was a long time ago buddy :)

Comment: Sure, but your answer makes it look like the latest version of ui-bootstrap is tested with 1.2.16, and that there is no later version than 0.12.1. Why don't you post to the actual landing page of ui-bootstrap, which lists the dependencies of all versions?

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct! I have edited the answer to provide more information about version history of this library. If it is still not clear enough please let me know so I can make it even better.